# Why use multiple regulators?

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, ldo

In many [devboards](http://www.atlas-soc.org/assets/de0-nano-soc.pdf#page=23) and reference schematics a couple of identical LDOs (or DC-DC) are used for high load. Is there a reason to use multiple low power LDOs instead of using single high power LDO?

Comment: Do you have a specific reference schematic, reasons may vary

Comment: I update my post with the link
http://www.atlas-soc.org/assets/de0-nano-soc.pdf#page=23
There is a couple of LT3080.

Comment: One flaw in the design: When combining two outputs from this LDO, (like in the 1.5V supply line) there should be a small resistor on the output to balance out the tolerances. See the datasheet as in my answer

Comment: Try looking for an adequate single LDO replacement for the two LT3080. Availability and possibly price might be the reason for this design.

Answer (score 1):

The [LT3080](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3080fc.pdf) as used in the design you've linked to is rated at 1.1 A, as the design is showing, it is supplying 1.5 V at 2.2 A max.

The speed of a smaller LDO is often higher than a larger LDO so the accuracy is higher, not sure on this but the availability could be an option, if you look for an 3 A 1.5 V LDO on Farnell, there is no SMD component available, only 1.5 A variants. However, most of the times in the design I work with, it has to do with heat dissipation and spreading. Not one hotspot but two less-heated spots are beneficial to the construction of the housing.

Refer to page 11 of the [LT3080 Datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/3080fc.pdf).

Comment: *The speed of a smaller LDO is often higher than a larger LDO so the accuracy is higher* Not sure if I agree with that. If you mean: "an LDO with a lower current rating can have a higher bandwidth resulting in better supply rejection" I can agree with that. Accuracy is purely a DC parameter and depends on the internal (bandgap) reference of the LDO (not the LT3080, it does not have a reference) and the voltage divider feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Reasons for using multiple voltage regulators / LDOs:

- To make different supply voltages, like in the example from your comment: 1.8 V, 1.5 V and 1.2 V.
- To share the load current between multiple regulators, like in the example from your comment, the 1.5 V is created by two LT3080 in parallel. Not all regulators can be used like this! In this design two are used to share the load current. One LT3080 can only deliver 1.1 A while more is needed on the 1.5 V supply.
- Share the power dissipation. It is much more easy and convenient to dissipate a certain amount of power across multiple devices. For example, the 1.5 V, 2.2 A supply form your example is derived from a 2.5 V supply. That means, at 2.2 A, (2.5 V - 1.5 V) * 2.2 A = 2.2 W needs to be dissipated. That's a lot to dissipate in one device. If that is shared between two devices, each will dissipate 1.1 W. Each device can now have its own heatsink. A device that dissipates 1.1 W will operate at a lower temperature than if it would have to dissipate 2.2 W (assuming same same heatsink and same ambient temperature).
- Make separate supplies so that a circuit that is sensitive to supply noise gets a "cleaner" supply.
- Make separate supplies so that a circuit that generates a lot of noise on its own supply doesn't "pollute" the supply voltage of other circuits.

Comment: point 2 and 3 are only valid in this topic, as the others do not apply in the setup for the shown design where input and output are combined

Comment: "To make different supply voltages" I talk about single voltage supply with high load. "To share the load current between multiple regulators" For what? "Share the power dissipation" Offcourse higly power LDO will have more power dissipation elements like bigger case or a larger thermopad. Not shure but the nois reducing with using multiple high noise LDO instead of taking a single low noise LDO seems a strange practice.

Comment: *multiple high noise LDO instead of taking a single low noise LDO* You're misunderstanding, it is not about the LDO's noise, it is about the noise on the supply that is generated by the circuits that run on that supply. For example logic circuits.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the other answer and being more specific to the schematic linked:

- The main reason is to power up some part of the circuit before others. This is especially needed if you have control electronic with an MCU handling powered output, the time the MCU boots up, you don't want to have potentially random output.
- Different voltages as said by the other answers.
- Higher current, sometimes if you have several supplies modules on a schematic and it isn't enough current, if you already use a specific chip to do the DC/DC conversion you rather put two of those to reduce the BOM size and BOM cost (higher quantity of a single component). The engineer also doesn't need to redraw another schematic / PCB layout for an additional rail.
- Noise can also be a factor, you may have "high power" DC/DC converter that drives mosfets and generates noise but want to have a separate one for the analog part.
- For large PCB where you need low voltage and high current (usually using CPU, RAM like a motherboard) you may want to have a short distance to the target area.
- Redundancy: For a safety-critical application like medical, self-driving cars, often the design has a fully redundant system which means several supplies, several identical processing units, like on the new tesla onboard computer.

Comment: "power up some part of the circuit before others." The precision tuning of startap time can be done with a ramp generator. The rough tuning can be done with capacitors. "Different voltages" The topic is about single supply. "to have a separate one for the analog part" In the topic example the 1.5V supply generats by two LT3080s connected together. "to have a short distance" Do you know examples of such design? I think main reasons are "The engineer also doesn't need to redraw another schematic" and "higher quantity of a single component". But is there physical reasons for such solution?

Comment: Yes, checkout computer motherboard, often they have several supplies for processor, and other components. Another reason can be redundancy, a good example is self-driving cars.